# Do not add a border to the right if progress bar value is 0

Tags: html, css

I created a grouped progress bar to load multiple progress bars with different colors. I am also adding `border-right` of `1px` in between each progress bars. I am trying to figure out if one of the progress bar has value `0` then don't add `border-right` of `1px` because right now if value is `0` it adds total of `2px` of border on the right. How can i fix it?

Please check the sample code below. I have a 3rd progress bar value `0` so it adds a border of `2px`.

https://codepen.io/Nick1212/pen/KvggVY

```css
.well-ProgressGroup {
  display: flex;
  background: #d3d4d5;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress {
  transform: translateX(-100%) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.well-background--concept1 {
  background: tomato;
}

.well-background--concept2 {
  background: blue;
}

.well-background--concept3 {
  background: purple;
}

.well-background--concept4 {
  background: red;
}

.well-background--concept5 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="u-pb--lg text-bold">Grouped ProgressBar Component Examples</h1>
  <div class="space">
    <div> Example: User earning all the points</div>
    <div class="well-ProgressGroup">
      <!-- react-text: 94 -->
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <div class="well-background--concept1 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 50%; animation:  0.5s linear 0s forwards loadbar;z-index: -1; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept2 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 75%; animation:  0.5s linear 0.5s forwards loadbar; z-index: -2; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept3 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 0%; animation:  0.5s linear 1s forwards loadbar; z-index: -3; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept4 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 250%; animation:  0.5s linear 1.5s forwards loadbar; z-index: -4; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation:  0.5s linear 2s forwards loadbar; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation:  0.5s linear 2.5s forwards loadbar; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <!-- react-text: 101 -->
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this in an app? Could you assign the width to a `data-width` attribute to the elements with the inline width? Then you could use `[data-width="0"] { border: 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not([style*="width: 0"])` selector to select elements which don't contain `width: 0` in their `style` attribute. Demo:

```css
.well-ProgressGroup {
  display: flex;
  background: #d3d4d5;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress {
  transform: translateX(-100%) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.well-ProgressGroup--progress:not(:last-child):not([style*="width: 0"]) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.well-background--concept1 {
  background: tomato;
}

.well-background--concept2 {
  background: blue;
}

.well-background--concept3 {
  background: purple;
}

.well-background--concept4 {
  background: red;
}

.well-background--concept5 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="u-pb--lg text-bold">Grouped ProgressBar Component Examples</h1>
  <div class="space">
    <div> Example: User earning all the points</div>
    <div class="well-ProgressGroup">
      <!-- react-text: 94 -->
      <!-- /react-text -->
      <div class="well-background--concept1 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 50%; animation:  0.5s linear 0s forwards loadbar;z-index: -1; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept2 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 75%; animation:  0.5s linear 0.5s forwards loadbar; z-index: -2; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept3 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 0%; animation:  0.5s linear 1s forwards loadbar; z-index: -3; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept4 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 250%; animation:  0.5s linear 1.5s forwards loadbar; z-index: -4; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation:  0.5s linear 2s forwards loadbar; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <div class="well-background--concept5 well-ProgressGroup--progress" style="width: 300%; animation:  0.5s linear 2.5s forwards loadbar; z-index: -5; height: 50px;"></div>
      <!-- react-text: 101 -->
      <!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @User7354632781 Glad to help you.

Comment: Nice way of doing it, I didn't know `:not` existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.well-ProgressGroup`. This allows your `width` value to also control the border.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to simulate a border. You can do it with background gradients.

see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEGGKV?editors=1100

```
.well-ProgressGroup--progress {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff),
                    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff),
                    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff),
                    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 0 0, 00;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0px 100%, 1px 100%, 100% 0px, 100% 0px;
}
```